# Laravel 5 intervention-image / intervention-cache: flexible url / routing

Tags: php, image, caching, laravel, laravel-5

Fiddling around with [Intervention 2.0](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/introduction) in Laravel 5. What I want is to manipulate images (size and cropping) and use Interventions [Image Caching](http://image.intervention.io/use/cache) to cache the images. What I basically try to achieve is the functionality of good old (and insecure) [timthumb.php](https://code.google.com/p/timthumb/).

**I started using this as an example:**

```
// routes.php
Route::get('imager/{src?}', function ($src)
{
    $cacheimage = Image::cache(function($image) use ($src) {
        return $image->make("files/image/".$src)->resize(100,50);
    }, 10, true);

    return Response::make($cacheimage, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg'));
});
```

**When I load an image like so:**

```
// template
<img src="{{"imager/image.jpg"}}"/>
```

It works fine.

But... In my situation images can be located in different (sub) directories, sometimes multiple levels deep. They are maintained in my CMS by their webmasters.

**examples:**

- files/images/image.jpg
- files/images/headers/image.jpg
- files/images/background/color/image.jpg
- img/common/logo.png

These image url's are loaded from a mysql table record.

**When such an images loads:**

```
// template
<img src="{{"imager/files/images/image.jpg"}}"/>
```

The route is not working anymore. After all, **files**, **images** and **images.jpg** are all url segments and *the amount of them could differ*.

**The image url (Bold) should be handled as one variable:**

Route::get('imager/**files/images/image.jpg**', function ($src = false)

Then I should be able to pass the sizing and cropping parameters off course. Because the img url length could vary I assume I could pass the parameters with a query like ?w=100&h=50&c=true or something?

---

**Update**

When I use a query parameter for the image url:

```
Route::get('imager', function ()
{
    $src = Input::get('src', 1);

    $cacheimage = Image::cache(function($image) use ($src) {
        return $image->make($src)->resize(100,100);
    }, 1, false); // one minute cache expiry

    return Response::make($cacheimage, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg'));
});

// template
<img src="{{"imager?src=files/images/image.jpg"}}"/>
```

This works.

Comment: Perhaps the best way to deal with this is by using mod_rewrite (if you're on Apache) and do something like:   RewriteRule ^imager/([.*])\.[jpg|gif|png]$  imager?src=$1

Comment: I had this prob too with a old Laravel 4 project. I added all the paths and sub-paths to the paths section in the imagecache config file.

Answer (score 3):

It is simple. You just have to tell Laravel that your image parameter consists of letters, slash, dash, underscore and dot (`'[A-Za-z0-9\/\.\-\_]+'`), because by default the framework matches everything but the slash `/`.

```
Route::get('imager/{image?}', function($src) {

    $cachedImage = Image::cache(function($image) use ($src) {
        return $image->make($src)->resize(100,100);
    }, 1, false);

    return Response::make($cachedImage, 200, ['Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg']);
})->where('image', '[A-Za-z0-9\/\.\-\_]+');
```

You can find out more about parameter binding in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#route-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Now you can now use the [URL based image manipulation](http://image.intervention.io/use/url%5D):

> Within a Laravel application it is possible to use the URL to manipulate images dynamically. The manipulated version of the an image will be stored in the cache and will be loaded directly without resource-intensive GD operation.
>
> An image has to be uploaded only once. All manipulations like resizing or cropping will be handled later, when the file is accessed via a HTTP request like this:
>
> `http://yourhost.com/{route-name}/{template-name}/{file-name}`